# Proof by induction - divisibility

Tags: induction

the question goes as follows: Use proof by induction to show that $2^{n+1}  +  5 \times  9^n$  is divisible by $7$.

I did a few things like $f(k+1)-f(k)$ to get to $2^{k+1}  +  5 \times 9^k \times 8$ but I dont understand what to do next

Comment: How about $f(k+1) - 2f(k)$?

Comment: @DougM i tried that and got to -5 x 9^(k+1)  did i do something wrong?

Comment: Write $9=7+2$ and use the binomial theorem.

Comment: @MarkViola thank you i slowly understood it, i never thought about it that way ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ be the statement that $2^{n+1}+5\times 9^n$ is divisible by $7$.

Base case: $n=0$, trivial.

Inductive Step: assume the statement is true for some $n = k\in\mathbb N$, we want to show the statement for $n=k+1$.

Then

\begin{align*} 2^{k+2} + 5\times 9^{k+1} &= 2\times 2^{k+1} + 5\times 9^k\times 9\\ &= 2\times (2^{k+1}+5\times 9^k) + (5\times 9^k)\times 7\\&=\cdots \end{align*}

Comment: um how did you factor out 2 from 5 x 9^k and where did the 7 +(5 x9^k) come from? sorry

Comment: i am confused with step 2 sorry if this is obvious to you

Comment: wait i think i get it

Comment: okay i get it nvm